# Update using mysqldb interface

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to figure out how to tell the difference when the rowcount returns a zero.

It can have two meanings:

1. The row was not found
2. The row was found but not changed

For example, and this is a very simple example just to illustrate a concept:

```
mysql> update tmp_tab set firstname = 'Jonhny' where id = '01001402450';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

In mysqldb, `cur.rowcount` would be 1.

Imagine the same command is executed again two days later:

```
mysql> update tmp_tab set firstname = 'Jonhny' where id = '01001402450';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

In mysqldb, `cur.rowcount` would be 0.

Now we execute this command:

```
mysql> update tmp_tab set firstname = 'Jonhny' where id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

In mysqldb, `cur.rowcount` would be 0.

My problem is how can I tell the difference between a row not being found and a row not being changed.

I am familiar with DB2, and DB2 it will return a +100 (not found) when the key does not exist, and a 0 when it exists, no matter if the values being updated remain the same or not.

Obviously I don't want to have to do a select to just figure that out, that would be extremely inefficient.

So is there a way to recognize a "not found" condition versus a "nothing changed" condition without executing another SQL query?

Comment: mysqldb's doc is quite clear: rowcount returns the number of affected rows for an update statement, not the number of matched records.

Comment: Have you tried cursor.messages or cursor.info if it has the right information? cursor.messages should map to mysql_info() C function, which is used by the mysql cli to display the message you are referring to.

Comment: Or conn.info - documentation is a bit confusing.

Comment: I removed the last paragraph of the question, since it seemed to lead nowhere and added no relevant information. Please revise that as appropriate.